Can't load the correct jar in Tomcat 9.0
Ok here is the setting:
I use Tomcat 9.0 / Java 1.8
I have 2 servlets.
Servlet A connects to a sqlserver2012 database
The new servlet B connects to a sqlserver2019 database
For servlet A in E:\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\ServletA\WEB-INF\lib I have a sqljdbc.jar from 2007 working fine
For servlet B this jar seems to old.
So I try to use mssql-jdbc-12.6.1.jre8.jar
If it put it in E:\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\ServletB\WEB-INF\lib it's not working
But if I put it in C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_181\lib\ext it works perfectly ... but ServletA doesn't work anymore
So it seems to me that Tomcat looks first in the JRE and use the jdbc here for every servlet so I can't put it here.
I thought that it would use the one from the WEB-INF\lib but it's not the case.
Due to the structure of our work envorinnement we are not using an IDE and we manually deploy the files (it's not great I know but I don"t have control over this)
I tried to add a manifest file with 'Class-Path: WEB-INF/lib/mssql-jdbc-12.6.1.jre8.jar' inside but to no avail.
The servlet structure is okay, we use it for multiple servlets
Classes are in E:\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\ServlerB\WEB-INF\classes (directly, no package)
with a web.xml like this:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<web-app
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    
  <display-name>SpicmiValidation</display-name>
  
   <servlet>
    <servlet-name>editSuspicionIso</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>editSuspicionIso</servlet-class>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>editSuspicionIso</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/editSuspicionIso</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>editSpicmiIso</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>editSpicmiIso</servlet-class>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>editSpicmiIso</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/editSpicmiIso</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 

 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>spicmiIsoServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>spicmiIsoServlet</servlet-class>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spicmiIsoServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/spicmiIsoServlet/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 
  <servlet>
  <servlet-name>spicmiIsoChoixSpecialite</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>spicmiIsoChoixSpecialite</servlet-class>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spicmiIsoChoixSpecialite</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/spicmiIsoChoixSpecialite/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
  
<jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <page-encoding>UTF-8</page-encoding>
    </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>

</web-app>

I tried to find solution through forum crawling and tools like chatGPT but nothing helped me
